# Сборка jar maven'ом с ресурсами вне jar

Tags: maven, java

Каким образом при сборке jar maven'ом одни ресурсы положить в саму jar'ку, а другие - рядом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже сам нашел ответ. Надо просто воспользоваться плагином maven-resources-plugin, настроить фильтрацию ресурсов.